# Printing list values asynchronously with multiprocessing Python

Tags: python, list, function, multiprocessing, iteration

I am trying to print out all the possible outcomes of `sets-sets3` values separated by elements with multi processing. The iterations tool gives out all the possible outcomes of the three values `Lower,Upper,number-number3`. So for the first iteration `Iteration(list_set, sets)` it will list all the numbers between `(2,2,30)- (11,11,3520)`, all these values are being stored in `sets-sets3`. With the multi processing tool I want to print out `sets-sets3` elements asynchronously.

Getting all the possible outcomes:

```
from itertools import groupby
from itertools import accumulate
import itertools
from numpy import genfromtxt
import multiprocessing 

def Iteration(a, b):
    for element in itertools.product(*a):
        b.append(element)
        
#Configs
Lower = [round(x * 0.5,1) for x in range(4,23)]  
Upper = [round(x * 0.5,1) for x in range(4,23)] 

#Number of days in chunks 
number = [round(x*10,1) for x in range(3, 352)]    #used for calculations with stand deriv and linear reg
number2 = [round(x*10,1) for x in range(352, 704)]
number3 = [round(x*10,1) for x in range(704, 1056)]      

list_set = [Lower, Upper, number]
list_set2 = [Lower, Upper, number2]
list_set3 = [Lower, Upper, number3]
sets = []
sets2 = []
sets3 = []

#getting the iterations
Iteration(list_set, sets)
Iteration(list_set2, sets2)
Iteration(list_set3, sets3)
```

Implementing multi processing

```
def Setruns(set_number):
    #function for going through all the configs
    for element in set_number:
        print("element 0:",element[0],"element 1:", element[1],"element 2:", element[2])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    with multiprocessing.Pool(3) as pool:               # 3 processes
        run1, run2, run3 = pool.starmap(Setruns, [(sets),(sets2),(sets3)]) # map input & output
```

Comment: If you want asynchronous behavior, you could add a `multiprocessing.Queue()` that you add your results into.

Comment: How would I be able to do that?

Comment: Is [`starmap_async`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.starmap_async) what you want?